# Trigger URL from Python

Tags: python, pyspark, rapidminer

i have an RapidMiner process, this process is saved on the cluster and can be triggered by an URL in the Browser. I would like to trigger this process at the end of my current script, which writes the raw data into a new Tabele.
When I open the URL in the browser the RM process starts normally and finished without an error.
I've tried the process via python 
requests.get (URL ...) and 
webbrowser.open (URL ....). 
This also does not create any error, however the RM process dosnt start.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure the cluster is getting the request. Any logs on rapidminer? What does the network tab in the browser say , 200? Post the code for the get request.

Comment: Check response code and body.

Comment: Yes, the RM process creats another table.The Code in the Browser is: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. <results serviceId="Scoring_THR"/> The Network tab Status is 200. 
the code for request is just: requests.get('http://Cluster with Port /api/rest/public/process/NameRMProcess?')

Answer (score 0):

ok i've solved it with:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False
response = session.get(url)
```